# Python - how to navigate through text file multiple lines backwards using seek()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What im trying to do is match a phrase in a text file, then print that line(This works fine). I then need to move the cursor up 4 lines so I can do another match in that line, but I cant get the seek() method to move up 4 lines from the line that has been matched so that I can do another regex search. All I can seem to do with seek() is search from the very end of the file, or the beginning. It doesn't seem to let me just do seek(105,1) from the line that is matched.

### This is the example test.txt

```
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line # Needs to seek() to this line from the 6th line. This needs to be dynamic as it wont always be 4 lines.
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
This is 6st line # Matches this line, now need to move it up 4 lines to the "2nd line"
This is 7 line
This is 8 line
This is 9 line
This is 10 line
```

#

```
def Findmatch():
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    print file.tell() # shows 0 which is the beginning of the file
    string = file.readlines()

    for line in string:
        if "This is 6th line" in line:
            print line
            print file.tell() # shows 171 which is the end of the file. I need for it to be on the line that matches my search which should be around 108. seek() only lets me search from end or beginning of file, but not from the line that was matched.

Findmatch()
```

Comment: Of course `file.tell()` gives you the end of the file, you've read the entire file into memory: `string = file.readlines()`. Since you are iterating over a list, (which oddly, you've named `string`), you can just use the list-indices... no need to mess with the file.

Comment: If your file is small, read it all into memory (you already do) and use list indices to navigate between lines. Forget file-based operations until the time you `.writelines()` your result.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind providing a simple example that I can build off of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've read all of it into memory at once with `file.readlines()`. `tell()` method does indeed correctly point to the end and your already have all your lines in an array. If you still wanted to, you'd have to read the file in line by line and record position within file for each line start so that you could go back four lines.

For your described problem. You can first find index of the line first match and then do the second operation starting from the list slice four items before that.

Here a very rough example of that (`return None` isn't really needed, it's just for sake of verbosity, clearly stating intent/expected behavior; raising an exception might be just as well a desired depending on what the overall plan is):

```
def relevant(value, lines):
    found = False
    for (idx, line) in enumerate(lines):
        if value in line:
            found = True
            break # Stop iterating, last idx is a match.
    if found is True:
        idx = idx - 4
        if idx < 0:
            idx = 0  # Just return all lines up to now? Or was that broken input and fail?
        return lines[idx:]
    else:
        return None

with open("test.txt") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()

print(''.join(relevant("This is 6th line", lines)))
```

Please also note: It's a bit confusing to name list of lines `string` (one would probably expect a `str` there), go with `lines` or something else) and it's also not advisable (esp. since you indicate to be using 2.7) to assign your variable names already used for built-ins, like `file`. Use `in_file` for instance.

EDIT: As requested in a comment, just a printing example, adding it in parallel as the former seem potentially more useful for further extension. :) ...

```
def print_relevant(value, lines):
    found = False
    for (idx, line) in enumerate(lines):
        if value in line:
            found = True
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
            break # Stop iterating, last idx is a match.
    if found is True:
        idx = idx - 4
        if idx < 0:
            idx = 0  # Just return all lines up to now? Or was that broken input and fail?
        print(lines[idx].rstrip('\n'))

with open("test.txt") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()

print_relevant("This is 6th line", lines)
```

Note, since lines are read in with trailing newlines and `print` would add one of its own I've `rstrip`'ed the line before printing. Just be aware of it.

Comment: Better add a test to see if `idx > 4`, else it will error out when that text is found in one of the first lines.

Comment: Absolutely, it really is just a rough example. I've added a test for not having any match, but you need to check for lower bound as well. Depends on what the desired behavior is in that case actually? Just start with the first line? Or is that a state indicating broken input? I've extended the example accordingly...

Comment: Hi Ondrej K, Thank you for your response, but this just prints out all the lines except for the first line. The goal is to match "This is the 6th line" and print that line out. Then move up 4 lines to the 2nd line and print the output of the 2nd line, which is "This is the 2nd line". Thankyou.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure what the intention behind that was... so more generic skeleton seemed to make more sense. I've added another example that does the printing now.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej K. This is a very helpful example. I think I can take it from here.